# How do I merge two lists of dicts with list of list in python?

Tags: python

how can I define a function

```
def join_data(data_1, data_2):
    
    #code
    
    return joined_data
```

where

```
data_1 = [{'paths': [[1,2,3]],  'pos': 1}, {'paths': [[1,2,3]], 'pos': 2},]

data_2 = [{'paths': [[6,7,8]],  'pos': 1}, {'paths': [[4,5,6]], 'pos': 2},]
```

The function should join paths into the same list by detecting if pos (always have 1 value) from the two data are the same, such that the output is

```
joined_data = [{'paths': [[1,2,3],[6,7,8]],  'pos': 1}, {'paths': [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 'pos': 2},]
```

I apologize if I am not clear in any way, and thank you for the help.

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear. Looks like you have fixed length lists, and you want to combine the same index items -- use zip. And to combine them, you want list concatentation, although you have a syntax error in the expected output. If it's supposed to use 'pos' then why are they lists instead of a dict?

Comment: Please clarify your desired output. "[[1,2,3][6,7,8]]" is not valid. Do you mean "[[1,2,3], [6,7,8]]"?

Comment: Also, what have you tried? It is important to provide an honest attempt and then pinpoint issues with your (ineffective) proposal, if that's the case

Comment: The way you wrote it, I would expect zip, but it would make more sense to make a dict with key=pos, value=paths. For example data_1 = {1: [[1, 2, 3]], 2: [[1, 2, 3]]} so you can then easily combine paths with the same pos.

Comment: Why would you have a list of dicts with unique values for one of the keys, rather than a dict that maps *the value for that key* to a dict with *the rest of the data*? Like, the *point* of the `pos` key-value pair is to tell you which dict you're looking at, right? That's why you want to use it as a basis for picking dicts to merge from the other list? So that tells you to use the value labelled as `pos` as a key to find the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an intermediate dictionary with the value of the 'pos' key as its key and merge the 'path' lists of the pos's dictionaries as value.  Then build your list bay reforming dictionaries from the items of the intermediate dictionary:

```
data_1 = [{'paths': [[1,2,3]],  'pos': 1}, {'paths': [[1,2,3]], 'pos': 2},]

data_2 = [{'paths': [[6,7,8]],  'pos': 1}, {'paths': [[4,5,6]], 'pos': 2},]

merged = dict()
for d in data_1 + data_2:
    merged.setdefault(d['pos'],[]).extend(d['paths']) 
merged = [ {'paths':v, 'pos':p} for p,v in merged.items() ]

print(merged)
[{'paths': [[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8]], 'pos': 1}, 
 {'paths': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], 'pos': 2}]
```

Comment: I would argue it makes more sense to have the intermediate-dict representation to begin with, and stick with it afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function;

```
def join_data(data_1, data_2):
    joined_data = []
    for i in data_1:
      for j in data_2:
        if (i['pos'] == j['pos']):
          joined_data.append({'paths': [i['paths'], j['paths']], 'pos': j['pos']})
    return joined_data
```

> Output:

```
[{'paths': [[[1, 2, 3]], [[6, 7, 8]]], 'pos': 1},
 {'paths': [[[1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6]]], 'pos': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A function which appends from one list into the other could be like this:

```
def join_data(data_1, data_2):
    joined_data = data_1.copy()
    for dic in data_2:
        pos = dic['pos']
        path_items = dic['paths']
        for d in joined_data:
            if d['pos'] == pos:
                d['paths'].extend(path_items)
    return joined_data
```